# correct static files setting

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm very confused about setting static files up. Every thing works fine(displays image, javascript, css) no matter what I try. So I'm confused which one is the right one.

Currently, this is how my project looks like

```
project
--project
---------static
---------media
--env
--static
--------media
--------static
```

And this is my code

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")
# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

When I do python manage.py collectstatic, I don't get any error but static folder that's in outer static folder doesn't contain anything. but media folder that's in static folder contains the files in media folder that's in project folder.

Also 
I have this for aws,

```
AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'project.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'realproject'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'ap-northeast-2'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

import datetime

date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(2 * 365 / 12) 
expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT")

AWS_HEADERS = { 
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400',
}
```

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing it right?

by the way, I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
and followed it, i'm not sure if I followed it right(displayed above) which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `python manage.py collectstatic` command looks for all your static directories and combines those file in the directory defined by the `STATIC_ROOT` setting.

In your case, `STATIC_ROOT` is set to `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static")`, i.e.

```
your_project/static/static
```

So this is where the static files are being collected to. If you want them in the outer static directory, you can change `STATIC_ROOT` to `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")`.

There is a good discussion of this in the excellent Django [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/).

There is quite a lot to take in in these settings, so here is a quick summary of each static setting as an example:

```
# this is the URL that django will look for static resources at
# - i.e. http://your_domain/static
# so this one is a URL used when by your web server and in template
# shortcuts.
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 

# this is where Django will look for static files to collect. 
# I.e. the search locations that collectstatic uses.  
# 'my_project/static' in this instance. You need to add the places
# you write your static files to this directory. For example, if you
# have several places where you are writing css files, add their
# container directories to this setting.
# it is a list of places to look for static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),) 

# this is where collectstatic will collect the static files to. 
# When you hook this all into your webserver, you would tell your 
# webserver that the /static/ url maps to this directory so that 
# your app can find the static content. It's a directory in your
# project usually.
# it's a single directory where the static files are collected together.
STATIC_ROOT
```

Comment: yes thank you this is why I was confused, then how come my media files are collected in a folder that's in my_project/static/media

Comment: This is due to your MEDIA_ROOT setting, which is `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")` i.e. `my_project/static/media`. Again, changing this setting is what will cause them to end up somewhere else.

Comment: I'm so confsued right now, I read more tutorials on this more confused I get. I tried changing like you said but static files aren't getting collected to static folder. I'm just going to leave it like 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

Comment: It is quite confusing at first - there are a lot of settings - you'll get there though :). I'll add a couple of details to the answer to try and help more

Comment: Basically, the list of `STATICFILES_DIRS` is where `collectstatic` gets its files **FROM**, and `STATIC_ROOT` is where `collectstatic` puts them **TO**. `STATIC_URL` is where the webserver looks for the files by URL.