# What is the correct settings for static files in django

Tags: django

I just started using django and I got confused over the static files. As per this post [correct static files setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171420/correct-static-files-setting) I understand that `STATIC_URL` is just like the name. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is the place where django will look for static files and `STATIC_ROOT` where the static files will be collected to. For my project I had the following file sys

```
rest
   |__ rest
           |__ settings.py
       pages
       static
             |__admin
             |__images
             |__vendor
                     |__bootstrap
                     
       templates
       manage.py
```

I decided to go for a project based approach when having my folders instead of a per app one. Some stuff was not working with the website landing page I had and I saw that I needed to `collectstatic` and so I did but I set the path to my already existing `static` file which did not let me at first but somehow ended up working. Out of nowhere my `static` folder had admin on it which I assume is from the admin app that comes with django, and my project finally started to work properly which is the confusing part. I decided to follow the post and included in my settings the following

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
```

Now I have a `staticfiles` folder along with my `static` folder. Also within the `staticfiles` folder I have everything I have in the `static` folder and that does not seem right and would like to know how to fix this. I am confused and a bit concerned that I will break everything again so any knowledge provided will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have used like this and its working fine:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and use to implement code in the main Project `urls.py` and not in-app `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, documents_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, documents_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Is the media folder a must? I have all my images in the static file under an images folder

Comment: media folder is for received files such as file uploads for user's profile picture @Alexander

Comment: I see, I have not yet done that as I will b using MySQL I will look into it more. What I wonder is if in my case I will have any issues after running the STATIC_ROOT to two different folder, first the static one and then another called staticfiles. Why do I need them both?